# Google map API: heatmaps doesn't work

Tags: google-maps, heatmap

I have the following piece of code to create a heatmap layer on a Google map:

```
Please, see https://pastebin.com/MrGVevxj
```

but it doesn't show any heatmap overlay on the map. However, the following example code works like a charm:

```
https://pastebin.com/87TDrGAq
```

Can you tell me what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question. The problem was with the size of the points to render the heatmap due to the different scales between the maps. For instance, the following value shows the heatmap:

```
var markersX13749 = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({ 
  data: markersX13749Data, 
  dissipating: false,
  radius: 0.7
});
```

In the apparently non-working piece of code, I was using the value `0.003` for the radius which is too small.